# How can same foreign key have multiple references in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to take the relationary representation to SQL but I get the following error (my sql then error)

```
CREATE TABLE REQUISITION
(REQNO CHAR(6) CONSTRAINT REQNO_PK PRIMARY KEY,
STAFFNO REFERENCES STAFF_CHARGENURSE(STAFFNO),
STAFFNAME REFERENCES SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL(STAFFNAME),
STAFFNAME REFERENCES SUPPLIES_SURGICAL(STAFFNAME),
STAFFNAME REFERENCES SUPPLIES_NON-SURGICAL(STAFFNAME),
WARDNO CHAR(6),
ITEMNO CHAR(6),
QUANTITY INT,
DATEORDERED DATE,
DATERECIEVED DATE);
```

---

```
STAFFNAME REFERENCES SUPPLIES_SURGICAL(STAFFNAME),
*
ERROR at line 5: 
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

How do I enter more than one foreign key in SQL? All itemNo's point back to a superclass in a MANDATORY, OR relationship which is why they're 3 instances of itemNo as a foreign key. Relationary:

```
Requisition(reqNo, staffNo, staffName, wardNo, itemNo, quantity, dateOrdered, dateRecieved)
    Primary Key reqNo
    Foreign Key staffNo references Staff_ChargeNurse(staffNo)
    Foreign Key itemNo references Supplies_Pharmaceutical(itemNo)
    Foreign Key itemNo references Supplies_Surgical(itemNo)
    Foreign Key itemNo references Supplies_Non-Surgical(itemNo)
```

Comment: 1. Supplies_Non-Surgical You shouldn't use - as a part of table name. 2. Why do you use STAFFNAME while in requirements it is itemNo column?

Comment: *'relationary'* is another new term to me. Where are these coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use explicit `CONSTRAINT` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE REQUISITION(
    REQNO CHAR(6) CONSTRAINT REQNO_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    STAFFNO REFERENCES STAFF_CHARGENURSE(STAFFNO),
    STAFFNAME data_type,
    WARDNO CHAR(6),
    ITEMNO CHAR(6),
    QUANTITY INT,
    DATEORDERED DATE,
    DATERECIEVED DATE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (ItemNo) 
         REFERENCES SUPPLIES_PHARMACEUTICAL(ItemNo), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (ItemNo)  
         REFERENCES SUPPLIES_SURGICAL(ItemNo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_3 FOREIGN KEY (ItemNo) 
         REFERENCES SUPPLIES_NON_SURGICAL(ItemNo)
);
```

Comment: The column names specified in the `foreign key` clause need brackets around them, e.g. `CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (ItemNo)`. Also there's a trailing comma after the last constraint.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Sure. Thanks for comment. As for trailing comma some dialects allow it. Here it will cause syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You want three constraints on `itemno`, not three `itemno` columns:

```
create table requisition
( reqno         varchar2(6) constraint reqno_pk primary key
, staffno       references staff_chargenurse(staffno)
, staffname     varchar2(20)
, wardno        varchar2(6)
, itemno        constraint fk_1 references supplies_pharmaceutical(itemno)
                constraint fk_2 references supplies_surgical(itemno)
                constraint fk_3 references supplies_nonsurgical(itemno)
, quantity      int
, dateordered   date
, daterecieved  date );
```

You can either name the constraints or let the system do it. In the example above, the FK on `staffno` was named `SYS_C0018431` on my database. Random names like this can create extra work further down the line.

Edit: just noticed you are using `STAFFNAME` in this example, in which case (assuming the three SUPPLIES_ tables have a primary or unique key on `STAFFNAME`):

```
create table requisition
( reqno         varchar2(6) constraint reqno_pk primary key
, staffno       references staff_chargenurse(staffno)
, staffname     constraint rs1 references supplies_pharmaceutical(staffname)
                constraint rs2 references supplies_surgical(staffname)
                constraint rs3 references supplies_nonsurgical(staffname)
, wardno        varchar2(6)
, itemno        varchar2(6)
, quantity      int
, dateordered   date
, daterecieved  date );
```

You could also define them at the table level or as separate statements, but then they can't inherit the (first) parent's datatype.

> All itemNo's point back to a superclass in a `MANDATORY, OR` relationship which is why they're 3 instances of itemNo as a foreign key.

I have not heard of 'MANDATORY, OR' relationships before and I don't think this is a standard data modelling term. Perhaps it is from some tool you are using.

There is no superclass here, and these are not instances of anything. You are defining three foreign key constraints referencing three separate database tables. A foreign key constraint is a rule that all values of the specified column must exist in the specified parent table.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to accomplish what is stated is to use record keys independent of data record. We use a GUID for each record. Foreign key constraint to one of several tables is accomplished by keeping a table of "keys" to which foreign key constraint is made. Each record in tables contain a unique key that must exist in key table, possibly accompanied by a code to indicate owning table. Where a foreign key defining a relation between items in other tables would reference a key from any of several tables the reference key table. Records in table defining relation would each have their own key in key table, as well. We have a parameterized stored procedure to insert records that obtains a new key value if one is not present in submitted record. New key is inserted in key table, then new record is inserted in respective table. An existing key would cause an exception on insert (should be an update.)

Note that in given case problem is design. One would use a single table of supplies, with a code defining the nature of supply item. Any reference to a supply item is a foreign key to one table. Categories can be 'viewed' by defining a view that selected items with a given category code or codes.

One would similarly use a single table for personnel.

This same problem is encountered in accounting of purchases. Some purchases are by 'order', some are 'direct' (or immediate). One has to be able to track orders. Solution is to defined a purchase table with 'category' code (e.g., 'O' or 'P') constraint. Then define tables to contain any data specific to order (e.g., vendor order number) or direct purchases (e.g., receipt image file) referencing purchase record.